# AppleScript Zip contents of folders without including any folders

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write an apple script app widget that will do the following.

When you drag multiple folders onto the widget it will zip the contents of each folder as a separate zip, these zips will be in the same directory as the widget.

The problem I am having is that I cannot work out how to remove the initial folder, when you unzip the archive, it needs to have all the files and subFolders loose.

For example if I zip myFolder/index.html
And myFolder/img/myImage.png

It should unzip as just index.html and img/my image.png

This would be incredibly useful to me, I have to zip the contents of folders about 50 times a day, renaming the zips with the name of the folder and copying them into the parent folder.

If someone could help with this I'd be willing to offer a mystery prize, I have a ton of steam keys lying about!

Thanks

Will

Comment: May you post your current script?

Comment: Hi, I've been looking at multiple scripts and trying to combine them, what I have asked for is slightly more advanced than these, as I'm asking for multiple folders at once, but something like this

Comment: tell application "Finder"     set theItems to selection     repeat with _a from 1 to (count of theItems)         set theItem to (item _a of theItems) as alias         set itemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of theItem         set fileName to name of theItem         set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of theItem as alias)         set zipFile to quoted form of (theFolder & fileName & ".zip")         do shell script "zip -r " & zipFile & " " & itemPath     end repeat end tell

Comment: I'd be willing to pay someone a small amount for their time, I know I am asking a lot as I am a complete novice to AppleScript

Comment: If you have more than one top level file in the zip, then it is extracted in a newly crated folder. It is expected behaviour. You can manually extract it in a pre-existing folder but then you won't know which files are from the archive. How do you zip/un-zip them? And any specific reason you want to use AppleScript?

Comment: If you zip files without folders included then they are extracted without a folder, I'm not sure what you mean, the reason I want to use apple script is that I have to zip the same folders in the same ways hundreds of times in the process of making html5 banners

Comment: Of course if you don't include a folder it won't be there. Let's say you have archive with one folder (oneFolder/) and that folder contains multiple items. If you extract that, on Desktop, it'll be extracted as oneFolder. However, if you have a zip with more than one top level file like multiple images, or folders. Then you extract that on Desktop a new folder will be created with the name of the archive, and it's content will be extracted there, not directly on Desktop. AppleScript has more use if you plan to automate apps, or control GUI, otherwise you'll be better off with a bash script.

Comment: I see what your saying now, however the reason I need the zip compressed folderless is due to the way the flash talking upload system works, so essentially it doesn't matter that on extract it would normally make a folder, I just need to zip it without the folder included in the zip, then move it up a folder

Comment: How are you zipping right now; are you using an app, or shell command? Can you post the code you use in your widget?

Comment: I'm asking for help because I don't have working code, I posted a snippet above, I'm looking for someone who knows how to do it

Comment: Im so sorry, I've been really busy at work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get started. If you don't understand a behaviour then feel free to ask.

```
on open theFiles
    repeat with x in theFiles
        set _path to POSIX path of x
        tell application "Finder"
            if kind of x is "Folder" then
                tell me to zipFolder(_path)
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end open

on run
    --  Handle the case where the script is launched without any dropped files
    open (choose folder with multiple selections allowed)
end run

on zipFolder(theFolderPath)
    do shell script "cd " & quoted form of theFolderPath & " && zip -r \"../$(basename $(pwd)).zip\" ./"
end zipFolder
```

Here is the [full applet](https://truck.it/p/SUJid0ML4b) Also you might wanna look into apps like LaunchBar, Alfred, and Keyboard Maestro, they help creating actions like this. There a are apps for archives such as Archiver, and Entropy which come with actions such as this.

If you wanna learn applescript, then here are a few features you could consider adding.

1. Make applet ask for a name for the archive, and use that.

   > display dialog handler, and pass results to the zipFolder handler as second argument
2. Reveal the file in Finder after creating it.

   > tell Finder to reveal
3. Move archive to a specific directory to upload it e.g. Dropbox

   > tell Finder to move/copy, or bash command `mv`
4. Make applet handle files too. If whatever behaviour you want it to.

Others can only help you so much because they might not fully understand dilemma you are facing, so learning this would be quiet useful, and fun.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I'll test it and get back to you, see if you want a prize

Comment: I've been told a grunt or bash script might be the way to go

Comment: The script works great, it just doesn't rename the zip's, they are both called work for me, I'll try and figure that bit out, thanks

Comment: This is driving me crazy, that script is amazing apart from the fact $(pwd) doesn not respect space. I have searched and searched, the solution seems to be to double quote it but i've tried everything with "'$(pwd)'" and double quoting different parts, just cant figure it out :(

Comment: @Wiplash, You have to escape the double quote with `\`. As you can see that `do shell script` also uses double quotes, so it'll think you are closing the quotes for the command unless you escape them. Just like with  `basename`, it'll be `\"$(pwd)\"`. The problem single quotes is that bash preserves the literal value. So `$(pwd)` would be passed to `basename` instead of it's value. Other solution would be use single quotes of do shell script, then you don't have to escape it. [Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting) to bash's guide.

Comment: Thanks for your help, let me know if you want a game key, I have tons.
I still have one issue. I've sorted out the overwrite problem I was having.

The script works perfectly as an app droplet. However if I run it through automator as a shortcut. It pops up with a folder dialogue box as it can't get the selection from finder.

I tried get selection as alias but can't get it to work. I'm guessing its the 'on open theFiles' line

Comment: `run` handler is executed when run from editor. Run is using `open` handler with the result to `choose folder`, hence the _"open dialog"_. So if you wanna run with selection, which I don't recommend as it can have unexpected results, you'll have to do `tell application "Finder" to set _sel to selection`, then `open _sel`. You can add me on Steam if you wish, tomatoes.dll, though I didn't answer for keys. Yes, bash script would have been good too, you can see the zipping is done with bash, but making use of dialogs and controlling apps would be more complicated. Use whatever you feel good with.

Comment: Thank you so much, can I offer you some free games?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested this is the final script I am using. This script takes any folders selected and creates a zip archive from each of them, renames them to the folder name and does not include the root folder within the zip. This is especially useful for making Flashtalking HTML5 banners.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if input is {} then -- no dropped items
        tell application "Finder" to set input to selection as alias list
    end if
    repeat with x in input
        set _path to POSIX path of x
        tell application "Finder"
            if kind of x is "Folder" then tell me to zipFolder(_path)
        end tell
    end repeat
end run

on zipFolder(theFolderPath)

    do shell script "tDir=" & (quoted form of theFolderPath) & "; cd \"$tDir\"; aZip=\"../$(basename \"$tDir\").zip\"; if [ -e \"$aZip\" ]; then rm \"$aZip\"; fi;  zip -r  \"$aZip\" ./"
end zipFolder
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much everyone who helped before. I have one more thing I need to do to the script. I'm trying to work out how to exclude certain file types from this operation. I think I need something like -x "*.scss" but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Any help is very much appreciated.